Error opening file with xarray in GitHub Actions
I'm encountering an issue with GitHub Actions when trying to open a file using xarray. The code works fine on my local machine and even in GitHub Codespaces, but it fails when running in a GitHub Action workflow.
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('https://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/erdMH1pp1day')
ds = ds.sel(latitude=slice(-31, -32), longitude=slice(114, 116))
print(ds)

The error message I receive is:
Error: curl error: Failure when receiving data from the peer
Warning: oc_open: Could not read URL

just to let you know:

The URL seems to be valid because it also works fine when using
netcdf4 (nc.Dataset) to open the same file.
I’ve checked thepackages and dependencies, so I don’t believe it’s related to that.

I suspect that the issue might be related to GitHub Actions specifically, as the code works fine elsewhere. Could anyone provide insight into what might be causing this issue in the GitHub Actions environment? Any suggestions for troubleshooting or resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
